# How to preserve TreeSet comparator?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Assuming that I constructed `TreeSet` with anonymous `Comparator` as follows:

```
    private TreeSet<Counter> mySet = 
        new TreeSet<Counter>(
                new Comparator<Counter>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Counter c1, Counter c2) {
                         // some weird comparison logic here...
                    }
    });
```

now I want to get a portion of the `TreeSet` equal or greater than `someCounter` as follows:

```
mySet.tailSet(someCounter);
```

**How can I make the portion of the `TreeSet` returned by `tailSet()` be based on the original comparator `mySet` was constructed with and not to get just an ordered set ordered by natural order?**

Comment: Why do you think `tailSet()` isn't using your comparator? If you're seeing strange results, I'd bet it's because your "weird comparison logic" is not obeying the spec.

Comment: @dty, according to the javadoc there is no guarantee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *already is* based on the comparator you created the `TreeSet` with.

Comment: I failed to find a guarantee in the javadoc.

Comment: "The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used."  That comparator is used for _all_ operations in the `TreeSet`.  The Javadoc doesn't say it specifically because it's meant to be obvious.

Comment: The words "greater than or equal to" are defined in terms of the comparator you give the `TreeSet`.  The elements in the `TreeSet` don't even necessarily _have_ a natural order, so how else could it possibly work?

Comment: I do not know where you cut this from. The taiSet javadoc JDK 6.0.26 says: "Answers a SortedSet of the specified portion of this TreeSet which contains elements greater or equal to the start element. The returned SortedSet is backed by this TreeSet so changes to one are reflected by the other." I do not understand why you think that the original Comparator is preserved.

Comment: @aviad What if you constructed the TreeSet using non-Comparable objects? That's what Louis is getting at.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, then according to the spec a ClassCastException will be thrown.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, I am focused. My previous comment was to answer your question (which can be easily answered by reading javadocs). I fail to recognize the correlation between your last comment and the question I asked.

Comment: @aviad According to the spec, no exception is thrown.

Comment: If you insist, you can look up the source on your own, but this is _absolutely_ a guarantee made by the Javadoc.  My quote, by the way, was from the _class_ level Javadoc: the second sentence in the entire page.

Comment: "@Marko Topolnik, then according to the spec a ClassCastException will be thrown."  False.  If you're using a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` comparing objects that do not implement `Comparable`, then the only way the `TreeSet` could possibly order them is with the provided `Comparator`.  Any other implementation wouldn't make sense.  If you wrote a ten-line program to test it, you'd see that the behavior we describe is actually what `TreeSet` does.